# Можно ли как-то задать псевдоним для подобного обращения?

Tags: php

```
$this->getConfig()['default_picture']
```

Например это. По мне слишком длинно обращаться таким образом к конфигу. Можно ли как-то сократить запись в подобном случае. Обдумывая это вспоминал про псевдонимы пространств имен, хотелось бы что-то подобное.

Comment: а если реализовать так ?

     $this->getConfig('default_picture'); //без параметров - весь массив, с параметрами- выбранные ключи.

Comment: +1

К тому же ваш пример в задании сможет работать только на php>=5.4